# AngularJs attributes vs scope in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

What is the difference while using variables though attributes vs scope while define directives? For example -

```
angular.module('tModule')
  .directive('tModule', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: true,
      templateUrl: function(element, attributes) {
        return  attributes.variable1;
      }
    }
});
```

versus if I use scope. like below -

```
angular.module('tModule')
  .directive('tModule', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        variable1: "=variable1",
        variable2: "=variable2"
      },
      templateUrl: function() {
        return variable1;
      }
   }
 });
```

What are the differences and advantages?

Comment: use '=' when you need two way data binding. It is used when you want two way data binding between controller and directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few differences based on your example:

1. In your top example, specifying `scope: true` means to create a new instance of the parent scope.  In the bottom example, using an object syntax means to create an isolated scope.  So, when you pass parameters to a directive using the scope syntax like that, you are inherently creating an isolated scope for the directive.
2. If you want to take advantage of two-way data binding (=) or method invocation (&), then you'd want to use the second method of passing through scope instead of attributes.